# C# : Make a property for a variable with a different name (shortcut)?

Tags: c#, properties

The normal usage for a property in C# is :

```
private int aVar;
public int AVar { get; set; }
```

or just

```
public int AVar { get; set; }
```

But for reason of clarity I prefer to name private attribute with an _ before :

```
private int _aVar;
```

and then a property :

```
public int AVar
{
    get
    {
        return (_aVar);
    }
    set
    {
        _aVar = value;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do some kind of shortcut to have something like :

```
private int _aVar;
public int AVar { get; set; } : link _aVar
```

?

(Other than : "Use the visual studio snippet you lazy bum.", or "In C# everybody uses aVar and a AVar so don't use your stupid _ and everything will be fine." if possible)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the first example, but that `aVar` doesn't do anything. And no, you can't do the latter. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: the stupid '_' is banish with StyleCop rule SA1309 ;) http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1309.html

Comment: @Xaruth [SA1309 is silly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215395/ca1500-vs-sa1309-which-one-wins), "everyone" uses the underscore prefix for private members.

Comment: Not sure I understand why `(_aVar)` has parentheses.

Comment: @CodeCaster "everyone" who wrote in C++ before ;)

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think `private int _aVar; public int AVar { get; set; } : link _aVar` is more clear than just `public int AVar { get; set; }`?

Comment: For people new to C#. And say you have a big object with method that call other attributes it goes much quicker to see what's private and what isn't I find. But I can still survive without _ it's more curiosity than a need.

Comment: If you don't want to do anything in the get;set; then just keep it AVar {get;set;} and Remove _aVar;
It is completely pointless to link _aVar to AVar if you don't want to do some sort of work in the get;set;

Comment: Yes Indeed... Didn't cross my mind.

Comment: @JayMee : "return (a_Var)" -> My school coding convention habit ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#6 there's a shorthand for this for *read-only* properties, but not for writeable properties.

Instead of

```
public int[] AVar
{
    get
    {
        return (_aVar);
    }
}
```

you can put

```
public int[] AVar => _aVar;
```

This only works for READ ONLY properties though. (You should not normally make an array property writable, by the way.)

Is that the sort of shortcut you were looking for?

However, note that for your specific example, you might as well just use an auto-property:

```
public int[] AVar { get; set; }
```

Comment: Perfect! That's what I wanted to know.

Comment: Does this not result in a *read-only* property rather than a *read-write* one?

Comment: @Rawling Er, yes. I've clarified my answer.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Fair enough :)

Comment: @ashtrail Please review my amended answer - you may wish to rescind the "answered" tick!

Comment: Oh yeah sorry for the [] it was a modified version of some of my code I copied and I didn't noticed I left it there.
I won't rescind the answered tick : it's still the most accurate answer, and anyway as Donald Jansen pointed out my question is a bit pointless anyway.

Comment: @ashtrail the `[]` doesn't really make much difference - the `=>` only works with read-only properties even if it's just an `int`

Answer (score 4):

In short, no.

I assume you're aware of the visual studio snippet `propfull [tab] [tab]`. This will create both a 'typical' member and property syntax for you.

Comment: OK thanks then, as I said in the comments this was more curiosity than anything else.

Comment: @ashtrail - nothing wrong with curiosity. It's good to experiment with what C# can and can't do, not a bad question in my opinion.